# Can a Monk's martial arts attack be used on a second opponent?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk

I killed my 1st goblin outright with my 2Handed quarterstaff roll.  Can I use my bonus action to attack the remaining goblin?  it seems this would be a little too much power for one person in a RP setting, but maybe I'm just overthinking it.

After looking in the PH all I can find is how to calculate the damage and such.  If the answer is obvious, I'm sorry.  The PH is written and organized strangely and it's hard to understand sometimes.

Answer (score 15):

> **Martial Arts**
>
> ...When you use the Attack action... you can make one unarmed strike as a bonus action. (PHB5e, 78)

This unarmed strike is an attack:

> "If there's ever any question whether something you're doing counts as
>   an attack, the rule is simple: if you're making an attack roll, you're
>   making an attack." (PHB5e, 194)

The same page specifies the three steps to making an attack:

1. Choose a target
2. Determine modifiers
3. Resolve the attack.

Your bonus, unarmed strike--which is an attack--starts with you declaring a target.

**So you can take your Attack action, and then do your martial arts attack on the same or another opponent, or even move and then make your martial arts attack.**

Comment: The *Great Weapon Master* feat on p.167 also weighs in on the side of 'new target for bonus attack'--otherwise the first benefit would be always-moot.